# Perl Read File and Split to an Array

Tags: arrays, perl, split

I have some Problem about the Splitting into an Array.

I want to split an empty line and save to an Array.

1.) First I read the File and save to a String ($configdata).

2.) Then I want split the String ($configdata) with the empty line.

**My Script:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my $pathconfigfile = 'config.conf';
my @configline;

open(my $configfile, "<", $pathconfigfile);

        while(<$configfile>){


                my $configdata = $_;


                my @configdata = split /\n\n/, $configdata;
                print @configdata[0] "\n";
                print @configdata[1] "\n";
                print @configdata[2] "\n";

        }
close $configfile;
```

**Configfile:**

```
Testingtttttttttttttttttttttttt
############################################
0987654345678909876MN09uz6t56789oiuhgölkjhgfr
0987654323456789098765fgnloiuztlkjhgfrtzuiknb

MegaMixoiuzt
############################################
09876543457890098765NSUDlkjhzgtfr67899ztz9098
098765435678987t87656789876567898765679097658

TESTINGPARTS
############################################
0987654567890098765hzzasza654567uhgdjdjfacdaa
9876545678987654mchfuiaq754567898765434567876
```

**My Wish Result:**

print @configdata[0];

```
Testingtttttttttttttttttttttttt
############################################
0987654345678909876MN09uz6t56789oiuhgölkjhgfr
0987654323456789098765fgnloiuztlkjhgfrtzuiknb
```

print @configdata[1];

```
MegaMixoiuzt
############################################
09876543457890098765NSUDlkjhzgtfr67899ztz9098
098765435678987t87656789876567898765679097658
```

print @configdata[2];

```
TESTINGPARTS
############################################
0987654567890098765hzzasza654567uhgdjdjfacdaa
9876545678987654mchfuiaq754567898765434567876
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use input record separator

```
open(my $configfile, "<", $pathconfigfile) or die "$!";
local $/;
my @configdata  = split("\n\n",<$configfile>);
print @configdata;
```

Comment: @Skydreampower If my answer is useful for you, click the tick button for accepted answer :)

Comment: I'm not sure if that really counts as 'using' the record separator, as you're treating the file as a single record, then splitting it.

Answer (score 3):

This is easier than you think, if you use `$/` - the record separator.

E.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

local $/ = "\n\n"; 
#chomp removes $/ from the field)
chomp ( my @configdata = <DATA> );

print Dumper \@configdata


__DATA__
Testingtttttttttttttttttttttttt
############################################
0987654345678909876MN09uz6t56789oiuhgölkjhgfr
0987654323456789098765fgnloiuztlkjhgfrtzuiknb

MegaMixoiuzt
############################################
09876543457890098765NSUDlkjhzgtfr67899ztz9098
098765435678987t87656789876567898765679097658

TESTINGPARTS
############################################
0987654567890098765hzzasza654567uhgdjdjfacdaa
9876545678987654mchfuiaq754567898765434567876
```

Gives:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'Testingtttttttttttttttttttttttt
############################################
0987654345678909876MN09uz6t56789oiuhgölkjhgfr
0987654323456789098765fgnloiuztlkjhgfrtzuiknb',
          'MegaMixoiuzt
############################################
09876543457890098765NSUDlkjhzgtfr67899ztz9098
098765435678987t87656789876567898765679097658',
          'TESTINGPARTS
############################################
0987654567890098765hzzasza654567uhgdjdjfacdaa
9876545678987654mchfuiaq754567898765434567876'
        ];
```

Alternatively, you could get cute with `map` to make an array of arrays:

```
chomp ( my @configdata = map { [split] } <DATA> );
```

Which will give you:

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            'Testingtttttttttttttttttttttttt',
            '############################################',
            '0987654345678909876MN09uz6t56789oiuhgölkjhgfr',
            '0987654323456789098765fgnloiuztlkjhgfrtzuiknb'
          ],
          [
            'MegaMixoiuzt',
            '############################################',
            '09876543457890098765NSUDlkjhzgtfr67899ztz9098',
            '098765435678987t87656789876567898765679097658'
          ],
          [
            'TESTINGPARTS',
            '############################################',
            '0987654567890098765hzzasza654567uhgdjdjfacdaa',
            '9876545678987654mchfuiaq754567898765434567876'
          ]
        ];
```

E.g.

```
$configdata[0][0] = 'Testingtttttttttttttttttttttttt'
```

Note - I'm using the inline `__DATA__` filehandle for illustrative purposes. You would use your opened filehandle. ( `chomp ( my @configdata = <$configfile> );` )

Also - `$/` applies to `while` loops, so each iteration of your `while` would be the chunk of text you're intending to operate on - so you could instead:

```
while ( <DATA> ) { 
    chomp;
    print "Start of chunk:\n";
    print;
    print "\nEnd of chunk\n";
}
```

Comment: $/ - wow, I've been using Perl for years and never come across this (nor the need to split files into records) but very useful.

Comment: `local $/ = "";` (paragraph mode) would make far more sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;
use TrigMod;

use Math::Trig;
use Math::Round;


print 
    'MENU
    1.  Calculate a if b and h are given.
    2.  Calculate h if a and b are given.
    3.  Calculate h if Y and a are given.
    4.  Calculate Y if h and a are given.
    ';
print "\nEnter Option";
my$opt=<>;


my$a, my$b, my$h, my$Y;


if($opt==1)
{
    print "\nEnter base and height b,h:";
    $b=<>;
    $h=<>;
    # b=6, h=4, a=5
    $a=TrigMod::geta($b,$h);
    $Y=TrigMod::getY($a,$h);
    print "\na=$a\theight=$h\tbase=$b\tangle=$Y";

}

elsif($opt==2)
{
    print "\nEnter sides a and b:";
    $a=<>;
    $b=<>;

    $h=TrigMod::geth_ab($a,$b);
    #a=5, b=6, h=4;
    print "\n$h";
    $Y=TrigMod::getY_ah($a,$h);
    print "\na=$a\tbase=$b\theight=$h\tangle=$Y";   
}

elsif($opt==3)
{
    print "Enter sides a and Y in degrees:";
    $a=<>;
    $Y=<>;

    $h=TrigMod::geth_aY($a,$Y);
    $b=TrigMod::getb_ah($a,$h);
    print "\na=$a\tbase=$b\theight=$h\tangle=$Y";   
}

elsif($opt==4)
{
    print "Enter sides a and h:";
    $a=<>;
    $h=<>;

    $Y=TrigMod::getY_ah($a,$h);
    $b=TrigMod::getb_ah($a,$h);
    print "\na=$a\tbase=$b\theight=$h\tangle=$Y";   
}
```